# Размер шифра в AES-128

Tags: криптография, aes

Размер шифра AES128 - 128 бит . Сколько это символов строки php ? (1 символ равен 8 бит?) тогда строка из 16 символов будет как раз под размер ключа?

Comment: PHP тут ни при чём. 16 символов получается, да.

Comment: А что значит "Размер шифра" ? AES блочный шифр, размер блока aes-128 - да 16 байт. Но это блок. Ключ может быть и 16 байт и 32. Ключ больше влияет на поведение таблицы перестановок, которую кстати, при большом желании то же можно взять нестандартную

Comment: Размер блока у блокового шифра отвечает только за то, какие порции  открытого текста берутся в работу. Если не хватает до длины блока - они дополняются. По вашему вопросу мне кажется, что вы думаете, будто ключ как то довольно легко складывается со строкой. Это не так. Лавинный эффект таков, что изменение 1 бита в блоке открытого текста ведут к изменению практически всех битов шифротекста. И размер ключа и размер блока это совершенно разные вещи

Comment: @Mike размер блока AES - 128 байт. Но суффикс "128" в "AES-128" означает именно длину ключа. AES-192 и AES-256 - это AES с блоком 128 бит, но с 192 и 256-битным ключом.

Comment: @Mike есть еще AES-192. А изменение констант в алгоритмах без четкого понимания как они повлияют на результат - нехорошо.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Да, я в общем в курсе, что таблицы подобраны математически и их изменение может сильно снизить криптостойкость.

Answer (score 1):

128 бит это 16 символов, но не у каждого байта есть читабельное представление, которое может быть корректно показано частью строки. Например, 11 - это вертикальная табуляция - несколько проблематично будет сохранить ее в виде строки.

Если ключ задаете вы сами - то хранить его в виде строки ок, но при этом вы ограничиваетесь примерно 5 значащими битами на байт (буквы+цифры), и реально значащая длина ключа составит 80 бит.

Если ключ приходит извне - в нем могут быть символы, которые не могут быть корректно прочитаны пользователем. Тогда есть пару вариантов строкового представления:

- Сохраять ключ как HEX-строку - 0011..EEFF - это по два символа на байт. 32 символа на выходе.
- Сохранять ключ в base64 - тогда длина составит 4/3 * 16 = 22 символа.